# Jquery не работает, где ошибка?

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь создать тестовый проект с использованием этой библиотеки, не работает в принципе, вот код индекса и скрипта:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#button").click(function() {
  $("#demo").html("Hello, World!");
 });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
        <title>Jquery Demo</title>
 
 </head>
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hi.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

На выходе вместо хеловорлда - чистый лист, в консоли ошибок нет, файлы все на месте...

Comment: Ну так все работает. Просто у вас нету кнопки с `id` `button`, которая по клику добавит `Hello world` к элементу с `id` `demo`...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за ответ, понял свою ошибку, это как ходить с ключами в руках и искать их по углам)

Answer (score 1):

В Вашей html странице нет ни элемента с `id="button"`, ни элемента с `id="demo"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#demo").html("Hello, World!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```